# Summernote copy image

Tags: javascript, summernote

I haven't found anything about this anywhere. How can I copy a selected image into the clipboard?
I have created a custom js that adds a button to the popover of the image which works fine but I'm stuck here:

```
$.extend($.summernote.plugins, {
        'imageCopy': function (context) {
            var self = this;
            var ui = $.summernote.ui,
            $editable = context.layoutInfo.editable,
            options = context.options,
            $editor = context.layoutInfo.editor,
            lang = options.langInfo,
            $note = context.layoutInfo.note;

            context.memo('button.imageCopy', function () {
                var button = ui.button({
                    contents: options.imageCopy.icon,
                    container: false,
                    tooltip: lang.imageCopy.tooltip,
                    click: function () {
                        var img = $($editable.data('target'));
                        console.log('copy image=' + img);
                    }
                });
                return button.render();
            });
        }
    });
```

So I don't really know how I can get the data from the currently selected image and put it into the clipboard.

Comment: Have you tried the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write)?

Comment: Yes, copying to the clipboard shouldn't be a problem, I just can't get the selected image data from Summernote

Comment: What does `$img` contain? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code to include the whole plugin

Comment: I just required the information of the content from `img`. It looks like a node, but i couldn't tell which kind of node it is (img, canvas...?) - anyway, i posted answer without it, that shows how to make use of the Clipboard API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just referred Summernote docs and other stuff. what I understood is it is providing `restoreTarget` attribute for getting reference of the selected image. You can get the source of the image through that and copy it to clipboard using Clipboard API.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/d1nz52c0/) is the code that I've tried.

Comment: Hey nice code, Is it possible to retrieve de parent's element from the <img> tag? I did some changes in my summernote, and added the tag <figure></figure> around the <img> tag, now I am doing the functions to float manually, so I need to access the parent's img to add a class, do you know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The snippet does not use a button but shows how to make use of the Clipboard API. Simply click on the image.

It will be blocked on iframes. The errormessage refers to https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes which depends on the flags allowed for the snippets here.

Also type "image/jpeg" returns an error while "image/png" works.

```js
img.onclick = ({ target }) => {
  fetch(target.src)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.blob()
  })
  .then(function(blob) {
    navigator.clipboard.write( [new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })]).then(
        function () {
          console.log("Yay");
        },
        function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
    );
  });
};
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/I6N0hf2.png" style="height: 100px;">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The problem is that I can't really get the blob from the image with Summernote so I can't copy it.

Comment: What does the variable `img` contain? What kind of node/object?

Comment: $($editable.data('target')); but I'm not sure if that's how I can get the selected image from Summernote.